# Mongoid ignores relation ids from params when saving an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

(Yes, I've tried `autosave: true`)

I have three models: user, post, comment. Comment belongs to a post and an user.

So in Comments#create I have the following line:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

The post_id is passed in params as `comment: {post_id: post_id}`. However, mongoid completely ignores it when it saves the object. Obviously I can solve it by adding something like `@comment.post = post`. Is it a proper solution or can I do it better and cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the one passed with params is in JSON format? Then it is in hash instead of in object format.

Probably, json cant be directly converted.

Try this

```
comment=Comment.new(:post_id => params[:comment][:post_id])
#try to replace symbol [:post_id] with string ["post_id"] if it did not work
current_user.comments.build(comment)
```